Laravel Sanctum Authentication with Nextjs
I have my api using laravel sanctum api for auth and in my api routes i have this
Route::get('/blog/{id}', BlogController::class);

and in my controller i have this
public function __invoke(Request $request)
{
   $blog = Blog::where('id', $request->id)->first()

    return response->json([
        'blog' => $blog
        'user' => $request->user()
    ]);
}

The problem is that i do not know why the user is null in my nextjs application even though i have logged in.
also if i add sanctum auth middleware to the route i am not able to access the page in my nextjs application.
any help to solve this will be appreciated
Note: i have also done this auth()->user() and auth()->id() still null

Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('/blog/{id}', BlogController::class);

try this  and pass bearer token also then auth()->id get

@UmerFayyaz Why will i need to pass bearer token when i am using laravel sanctum?

Bcz due to bearer token laravel understand  this user is authenticate.
